# Telegraf - multiple input, multiple output

Tags: influxdb, telegraf

I want to write every input on the relative DB (ex. input1 --> DB1, input2-->DB2) on influxdb
This is my telegraf.conf

```
#                            OUTPUT PLUGINS                                   #
[[outputs.influxdb]]
urls = ["http://172.18.0.2:8086"]
database = "shellyem"
namepass = ["db1"]

#                            OUTPUT PLUGINS                                   #
[[outputs.influxdb]]
urls = ["http://172.18.0.2:8086"]
database = "shell"
namepass = ["db2"]

#                            INPUT PLUGINS                                    #
[[inputs.db1]]
  urls = [
"http://192.168.1.191/emeter/0",
  ]
  timeout = "1s"
  data_format = "json"
 
#                            INPUT PLUGINS                                    #
[[inputs.db2]]
  urls = [
"http://192.168.1.192/emeter/0",
  ]
  timeout = "1s"
  data_format = "json"
```

It doesn't work because i don't understand how namepass works, can you help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

But it's so simple, just read for dindirindina
ok copy and paste the code below

```
[[outputs.influxdb]]
  urls = ["http://172.18.0.2:8086"]
  database = "Mirko"
[outputs.influxdb.tagpass]
  influxdb_tag = ["Mirko"]
[[outputs.influxdb]]
  urls = ["http://172.18.0.2:8086"]
  database = "Simone"
[outputs.influxdb.tagpass]
  influxdb_tag = ["Simone"]


[[inputs.http]]
 urls = [
  "http://192.168.1.191/emeter/0",
  "http://192.168.1.191/emeter/1"
 ]
 data_format = "json"
  [inputs.http.tags]
   influxdb_tag = "Mirko"

[[inputs.http]]
 urls = [
   "http://192.168.1.201/emeter/0",
   "http://192.168.1.201/emeter/1"
 ]
 data_format = "json"
  [inputs.http.tags]
   influxdb_tag = "Simone"
```

*improved formatting (added space)